# EV3 Classroom: Project, Programs and MyBlocks

Tags: ev3, mindstorms

There are two useful features in the EV3 MINDSTORMS (LabView-based) software, that do not appear to be in the EV3 Classroom (Scratch-based) software.

1. We could create a project and write multiple programs under that project.
2. Once we create a myblock for the project, all the programs within that project could use the myblock.

I can not figure how to do this in EV3 Classroom. Specifically, how do I share "myblock" across multiple programs? Any help is really appreciated.  Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

These features are indeed missing in the EV3 Classroom software. And since EV3 is retired, it seems unlikely they will be added.

Ideas for alternate solutions:

- Copy the entire program to a new file to copy My Blocks.
- Put everything in a single file and create your own menu interface to run sub-programs.